# Handling multiple filters (params) cleanly in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a class called Post, and I need to be able to accommodate the following scenarios:

- If a user selects a category, only show posts from that category
- If a user selects a type, only show posts with that type
- If a user selects a category and type, only show posts from that category with that type
- If a user selects nothing, show all posts

I'm wondering if it's inevitable that my controller is just going to look gross with a ton of conditionals... here's my flawed approach at tackling this – does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = current_user

    # If a user has not specified a type or category, 
    # show them everything
    @posts = Post.all

    # If a user has selected a category, but no type, only 
    # show posts from that category.
    if params[:category] && !params[:type]
      category = Category.find(params[:category])
      @posts = @category.posts
    end

    # If a user has selected a category and a type, only show
    # posts from that category with that type
    if params[:category] && params[:type]
      category = Category.find(params[:category])
      type = params[:type]
      @posts = category.posts.where(post_type: type)
    end

    # If a user has selected a type but not a category, show all 
    # of the posts with that type 
    if params[:type] && !params[:category]
      type = params[:type]
      @posts = Post.where(post_type: post_type)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll be better off following the convention of "fat models, skinny controllers", meaning you should put this kind of logic in the model itself.  The `Post` class should be able to report which posts correspond to your conditions, so you can define a method to do that:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.by_category_and_type(category = nil, type = nil)
    return where(category: category, type: type) if category && type
    return where(category: category) if category
    return where(type: type) if type
    all
  end
  ...
end
```

Then in your controller you can just call

`@posts = Post.by_category_and_type(params[:category], params[:type])`

I haven't tested this, but I think it should do the trick.  Let me know if it doesn't!

Comment: Cheezus! This is definitely a pattern we should be using.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code a bit like this:

controller:

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @posts = find_posts 
  end

  private

  def category
    Category.find(params[:category])
  end

  def find_posts
    if type = params[:type]
      if params[:category]
        category.posts.of_type(type)
      else
        Post.of_type(type)
      end
    elsif params[:category]
      category.posts
    else
      Post.all
    end
  end
```

Add the scope to your `Post` model, name it as you like:

`scope :of_type, ->(type) { where(post_type: type) }`

I recommend you using https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure 
The code above is not the best, but you can improve it with this gem.
You can even create a new class which will be responsible for finding posts and use this class in your controler.